# Is it possible to declare a function that belongs to a singular instantiation of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates

The application I have in mind is something akin to a `Vector<size>` class, in which I wish to declare

```
CrossProduct(const Vector<size>& other)
```

only for when size is 3. I know there are ways I can hack around it...

- Include a function definition only for size=3
- let all other sizes yield linker errors
- Do a static assert at the start of the method to check if size is 3

Is there any way to properly only declare the member function for a particular instantiation?

Comment: Are you looking for compile-time support, or would generating a run-time error satisfy your needs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
template <class Type, size_t Size>
struct EnableCrossProduct
{

};

template <class Type>
struct EnableCrossProduct<Type, 3>
{
  void CrossProduct(const Type & other){}
};

template <size_t Size>
struct Vector : public EnableCrossProduct<Vector<Size>, Size>
{
};
```

Comment: Have fun repeating `// whatever`.

Comment: I would rather not re-write the entire class in order to add one or two functions.

Comment: @GManNickG There we go, fixed

Comment: Looks good! Could make the destructor of `EnableCrossProduct` protected and yada yada but the idea is the same.

Comment: @GManNickG interesting, good point. For anyone else wondering why, making the destructor of EnableCrossProduct protected prevents anyone from instantiating `EnableCrossProduct` alone, or calling `delete` on an `EnableCrossProduct *`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can get the size info at compile-time, you can use std::enable_if.

```
template<int N>
struct Vector
{
    static const int size = N;
    double data[N];
    // ...

    template<class V>
    double CrossProduct( const V& other, 
        typename std::enable_if< size == 3 && V::size == 3 >::type* = 0) const
    {
        // ...
        return 0;
    }
};

void foo( const Vector<3>& v3, const Vector<4>& v4 )
{
    v3.CrossProduct( v3 ); // Ok
    v3.CrossProduct( v4 ); // Compile-time error
}
```

You might just want to make that condition in the enable_if `size == V::size`.

Comment: Both `CrossProduct(v3)` and `CrossProduct(v4)` are compile time errors... it's a member function.

Comment: Your second SFINAE example isn't correct. It'll fail it the mere instantiation of `Vector<4>`, for example, without even trying to use `CrossProduct`. Also, specialization means repeating information (`// ...`) or factoring it out.

Comment: As far as @GManNickG's point about specialization meaning repetition, it can. But here if the OP doesn't want to support cross product for Vector4's or if he only want to support it for vectors of the same size, he could write it once with enable_if.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer the `static_assert` method.  This

- leads to the clearest error message
- is appropriate since there is no need for SFINAE
- is the easiest way.

Comment: Yeah...It IS nice, but it's unfortunate that it pollutes the Itellisense of Visual Studio. A minor grievance, I know, but it affects the usability of the class a bit for my purposes.

Comment: There are people out there that don't code with Intellisense (like me). If they use your code, you have to think of them as well.

Comment: Ideally I would find a solution that fits both parties' needs. Seems it's unlikely though. It didn't hurt to ask =)